# Not able to select check box for dynamic input ID value

Tags: checkbox, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, selenium2library

Below is the html for two check boxes, and my intention is to select a checkbox using it's label as 'XERU' or 'SYM'. In Robot Framework, the keyword 'Checkbox Should Be Selected' uses Key attributes; ID and name as it's locator, but here ID is dynamic for each label.

So I need to frame an Xpath for the check box selecting it's ID / Name but not to be hard coded within the test suite.

```
<input id="ctl00_PageBody_chklistVirtualAddressingGroups_5" name="ctl00$PageBody$chklistVirtualAddressingGroups$5" type="checkbox"/>
<label for="ctl00_PageBody_chklistVirtualAddressingGroups_5">XERU</label>
<br/>
<input id="ctl00_PageBody_chklistVirtualAddressingGroups_6" name="ctl00$PageBody$chklistVirtualAddressingGroups$6" type="checkbox"/>
<label for="ctl00_PageBody_chklistVirtualAddressingGroups_6">SYM</label>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code. This code is based on HTML you provided. Please try to provide more information.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'XERU')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'SYM')]")).click();
```

Comment: I am executing using  Robot framework,your answer works on Selenium  @Maninder.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something along these lines:

```
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    4 sec    1 sec    Click Element    xpath=//label[contains(text(), 'XERU')]
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    4 sec    1 sec    Click Element    xpath=//label[contains(text(), 'SYM')]
```

If this fails, can you give us further information as to why there's a problem?

Comment: This said, why do you not do an initial stage simply to find the ID of the elements you need, then use the checkbox keyword from there?  Perhaps a bit more stable and maintainable

Answer (score 0):

Use xpaths as -

```
(//label[text()='XERU']/preceding::input)[last()]
(//label[text()='SYM']/preceding::input)[last()]
```